# Java: Bitwise operation for flag checking

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, operations

I'm trying to check whether or not a number has the second bit flag (ie 0000 0010).  My code is as follows:

```
int flags = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
String strflags = Integer.toBinaryString(flags);
flags = Integer.parseInt(strflags);
int secondBitTest = Integer.parseInt("00000010", 2);
if((flags & secondBitTest) == 2) {
    System.out.println("YES");
}
```

However I think I might be doing this wrong, since when I try to input 147 nothing is returned.

Comment: Why aren't you just using standard binary operators? `flags & 0b10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if any bit is set using this code that I found [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/).

```
if (x & (1<<n) != 0) {
  //n-th bit is set
}
else {
  //n-th bit is not set
}
```

x is the number you wish to check, and n is the bit you want to check. The algorithm works by left-shifting the number 1 by n, and AND-ing it with x.

Comment: You got the precedence of `&` and the comparison wrong (better use `!= 0`).