# How can i acknowledge that an NFC tag has been read

Tags: java, android, nfc

Hey i've been working on an app for a school project that requires me to acknowledge that an NFC tag has been tapped with the sensor. Is there a way to circumvent reading the data from the tag and just register thet a tag has been read. Im working with Android Studio and all the threads i can find are 4-5 years old, so i cant quite adapt them to the current version of android. If anyone has any insight i'll be very greatful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered here: 
[Enable/Disable counter for NTAG213](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665215/enable-disable-counter-for-ntag213)

I recommend using Ntag213, Ntag215, or Ntag216, because they do have the "scan counter" feature.